# Whats the point in conserving electricity if the AC current produced cannot be stored?

Tags: electricity, energy-conservation, electric-current

If we cannot save the ac current produced in a battery or some device like the DC current there is no point in conserving it because current once produced should be consumed somehow!!

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that the energy bounces back if you don't use it (note that energy $\neq$ current!).

Comment: You aren't saving current (neither DC nor AC). What you are saving is energy. Hydroelectric pumped storage can do it just fine, even when the pump engines are operated with AC voltages and currents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torque on electricity generators is continuously adjusted to keep them running at a constant speed (e.g. 60Hz in the US and 50Hz in the UK). When you turn on some electrical item the current it consumes places a greater load on some electricity generator somewhere and this reduces the speed. To counter this, at the generating station more torque is applied to the generator to keep the speed constant. At a conventional generator this means increasing the steam flow, which means increasing the amount of coal burnt and increasing the amount of carbon dioxide released.

The converse is also true. When you turn off an electrical item it decreases the load on the generator, and this means less coal has to be burnt.

In practice the effect on the generator of you turning on/off one device is unlikely to be noticable. However when millions of people turn things on and off it makes a large difference.  This is the origin of the notorious [TV pickup effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_pickup).

The point is that you're starting with the wrong assumption. Power companies don't just generate power and then not care if anyone uses it or not. They only generate just enough power to supply the demand.

Answer (score 1):

Power generation and supply management is not easy and it is to their credit that most of the time power companies supply people with AC at the same voltage no matter what the demand for power is. So when we turn on appliances we do not see the voltage drop as a result. Or more realistically when everyone gets home from  work and starts cooking/ boiling kettles etc. we do not notice a drop in voltage supplied because the power companies monitor things closely and generate more AC - or rather use more energy to meet the need.

Reasons to conserve AC
* Whatever energy you use has to be produced somewhere else in a power station. 
* You pay for whatever energy you use.

If everyone used less power then less coil/gas/(other resource) would be used to generate power.

Finally, AC power can be 'stored' by, for example, conversion to DC and battery storage. - but the point is that if everybody uses lots of AC the power companies have to use more energy to generate the AC - if we use less they don't need to use so much energy to generate AC.

Day to day the main reason for most people to save AC is to try to keep their electricity use bill/costs as low as possible.